# How to use latest version dart package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am using Flutter on Android Studio. And I want to use some package that null safety. I can not use any package when this package's title has. I tried Flutter upgrade and I upgraded to the latest version. But it still is not working. Also, I upgraded the latest Dart package. Lastly, I used stable mod. But I still get the error message.

I want to use accordion 2.5.1. It has null safety title.

environment:

```
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.5"
```

I tried to make :

environment:

```
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

But I still get this error message:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.11.0-213.1.beta.

Because unnamed_cv requires SDK version >=2.11.0 <3.0.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because unnamed_cv requires SDK version >=2.11.0 <3.0.5, version solving failed.)
```

Also, You can see my terminal message:

```
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\unnamed_cv>flutter packages pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.

The current Dart SDK (3.0.5) only supports null safety.
```

While I use  accordion 2.5.1. or other high version packages. I always same error. How can I fix it?

Also, You can check when I wrote to the terminal "flutter doctor -v" I am getting this message:

```
 Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at C:\Users\user\Documents\flutter_windows_1.22.2-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (7 days ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.31702.278
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.134
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 114.0.1823.43

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

Comment: the `accordion` package still use sdk `<3.0.0`,  have you try to change your sdk ?

Comment: No. I do not know how to do it. I just used to "flutter upgrade" on terminal and It works.

Comment: Is it possible you have two versions of dart installed? flutter is bundled with a version of dart so you don't have to install dart separately. It appears from the error messages that you have both a `2.11.0-213.1.beta` dart sdk, and a `3.0.5` dart sdk.

Comment: "Is it possible you have two versions of dart installed? " How can I check it ? So, What should I do?

Comment: I updated my question. You can check ıt. When I wrote to the terminal "flutter doctor -v". Also, I downgrade my 3.0.5 to 3.0.0 SDK version. My problem is when I do 2.11.0 I getting error message.

Comment: I check it at File> Settings > Language&Frameworks > Dart. It shows me version: 2.11.0-213.1.beta. But When I check it at terminal it shows me 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your own pubspec.yaml file to have at least SDK version 2.12.0 as the error message is telling you:

```
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.
```

Change your pubspec to something like this (given you seem to be using Dart 3):

```
  sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"
```

Accordion version  2.5.1 is up-to-date with the Dart/Flutter versions:

https://github.com/GotJimmy/accordion/blob/master/pubspec.yaml

PS. don't worry about `sdk < 3.0.0` in their pubspec, pub is ignoring that as Dart 3 is backwards compatible with 2.12+.

Comment: I guess my Sdk is a little bit buggy. Do you suggest erased all sdk and completely install again? Because I check it on Android Studio settings. İt is still an old version is. But İf I check it on terminal it is using latest version on sdk.

Comment: I found the solution. Just download it latest sdk. And run it. After that, All codes are running smoothly.